# Azure MSI - is there a plan to support cloud services?

Tags: azure-managed-identity

It seems like classic cloud services are not supported.
Only app service and azure functions.

Is Azure going to add that?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. We will help with programming problems, which this is not. The question is likely to be deleted as off topic. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for more information

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about the service but rather the project management for the service.

Answer (score 1):

More services will be added soon. However, currently there is no plan for the classic cloud services at this point

Comment: Can I just add how much this is needed for cloud services?  They are the workhorse of applications at scale and need this badly.  I'm trying to work around the lack of it right now and finding it nearly impossible to do in the most secure way possible.